# Dart equivalent of Apache Commons Collections Bag

Tags: dart

Is there a collection in *Dart* that allows storing multiple items along with their repetition count? For instance, such a collection is in Apache Commons Collections (*Java*) and is called *Bag*. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`more` package](https://pub.dev/packages/more) contains a [`Multiset` class](https://pub.dev/documentation/more/latest/collection/Multiset-class.html) that does exactly that.
The [`Bag.getCount` method](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/Bag.html#getCount-java.lang.Object-) from Apache Common Collections corresponds to [`Multiset.operator[]`](https://pub.dev/documentation/more/latest/collection/Multiset/operator_get.html).